# PHP unread_bytes work in PHP 5.3 but not in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

I have a problem with a connection to a telnet-server using PHP sockets. I've a finished telnet class, but on my other server did that class not work because of the stream_get_meta_data unread_bytes value. Does PHP have changed that in Version 5.4? I can't find what about this change.

The code that i use:

```
        $buff = '';
        while (!feof($this->socket)) {
            $buff .= fread($this->socket, 1024);
            $stream_meta_data = stream_get_meta_data($this->socket);
            if ($stream_meta_data['unread_bytes'] <= 0)
                break;
        }
```

Can anyone help me or say me, what can i change?

Comment: Welcome to 2014, PHP 5.3 is not supported anymore, PHP 5.4 is almost not supported, everyone and their mother suggest you upgrade to PHP 5.6 or at least PHP 5.5. As of documentation: `unread_bytes: You shouldn't use this value in a script.`

Comment: Well, it's the internal buffer.. So... no guarantees about what's actually left to read. Doesn't the sole `feof()` work for you?

Comment: Say thanks to Debian, the newest release is PHP 5.4.x! feof() dont work correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Aredon build PHP5.6 from generic binaries

Comment: Tahnk you. I would do that, but how can i run my script? feof must abort/stop that _while_, when the socket gives no response back, right? Than i do not need stream_get_meta_data['unread_bytes']. Do i see this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clearly state what your code snippet is supposed to do:

1. read bytes until the socket connection is shut down, or
2. read bytes that are available at the moment, on a live connection.

But your comment *feof() dont work correctly* suggests that you're after 2., since a `feof()` check would be sufficient for 1.; cf. the comment from Wez to the "Not a bug" [**unread_bytes always 0**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18373):

> unread_bytes is the number of bytes remaining in PHPs buffering layer
>   after the last read.
>    If you have consumed all data from the buffer
>   on a prior read, unread_bytes will remain at zero until you next read
>   a chunk of data from the network.
>    So, unread_bytes should not be
>   used to determine if more data is pending; you should use either:
>
> feof() to detect end of file. 
>       Don't forget that you
>    can use non-blocking mode here.
>
> PHP 4.3 has a new function
>    called stream_select() which    behaves like socket_select() from the
>    sockets extension,    but works on all files returned by fopen() and  
>    fsockopen().  You can use it to test which files are    ready for
>    reading/writing and also specify a timeout.

So, if you want 2., you can use `stream_select()` or `socket_select()`.